# objective c-how can i decrement the number in uilabel when text is type in texfield in ios?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Here is my code:

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        //_length -= 1;
        //[self.lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.length]];
        _lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[AnswerText.text length]];

        NSUInteger newLength = [AnswerText.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength > 15) ? NO : YES;


    }
```

in this i can limit up maximum number which have to filled in `textfield`, but i need to decrement the label which have already value `15` it should be decremented when i started typing on `textfield` by `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all set delegate for this textField.
Try this code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == AnswerText) {
        if (([AnswerText.text length] + [string length]) > 15) {
            return NO;
        }

        _lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)(150 - ([AnswerText.text length] + [string length]))];
    }

     return YES;
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: In order to handle the case where someone selects part of your textField and replaces it (by typing or pasting), it's more accurate to use the length of what the textField **will** be after editing.  Something like: `NSMutableString *tempString = [AnswerText.text mutableCopy]; [tempString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];` and compare with `[tempString length]`.

Comment: Yes, @PhillipMills .